# How can I return a value that is missing from an original list in java?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

If I have two arrays and the first one is containing the original values, and the second one is holding the changed values.

How can I see if any value is missing from the changed list?

For example:

```
Array one: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

Array two: 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

Obviously in Array two, number 2 is missing. How can I get this missing value without checking the size of arrays as this doesn't matter.

Another example could be:

```
Array one: 1,2,3,4,5
Array two: 1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4
```

Still doesn't contain the "5".

Comment: One solution might be to clone list one, then `removeAll(list2)`. Anything left over is not present in list2.

Comment: What about "list one: 1, 1, 1" and "list two: 1" - where list one contains more copies of an item than list two?

Comment: What exactly do you have? 2 arrays or 2 lists?

Comment: 2 arrays, sorry for referring to lists, been using lists too.

Comment: Are the values in your array in some small range?

Comment: Also are the numbers sorted as in your examples?

Comment: There are 25 numbers in each list, one list is sorted, one is jumbled. Sometimes the numbers are the same in the second list so I want to be able to see what number is missing from the original sorted list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use function `List#removeAll()`:

`first.removeAll(second);`

Now the list contains only what wasn't in the second. Note that you must clone the first list before removing items if you plan on using it.

Comment: what if he has duplicates?

Comment: @user1631616 the way OP explained it, I assumed he doesn't care about that (I only considered if there is a number missing). But since I answered he added that he's using arrays not lists, so this is not much useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are aiming for efficiency, I would suggest sorting the lists first (if they aren't sorted beforehand) and removing all the repetitions of a number, past the first one in both lists. This way every element in a list will be present once at most.

Then you iterate over both lists at the same time, comparing their elements. If both elements match, you remove both values from both lists. If not, you move forward in the list of the smaller element of the two. After elements in one of the lists run out, both lists are left only with unique elements, that were not present in the other list.

```
public void compareLists(ArrayList<Integer> list1, ArrayList<Integer> list2) {

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while (i < list1.size() && j < list2.size()) {
        if (list1.get(i) == list2.get(j)) {
            list1.remove(i);
            list2.remove(j);
        } else if (list1.get(i) < list2.get(j)) {
            i++;
        }
        else {
            j++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Unique elements in first list: ");
    for (Integer num : list1) {
        System.out.print(num + " ");
    }

    System.out.println("Unique elements in second list: ");
    for (Integer num : list2) {
        System.out.print(num + " ");
    }
}
```

This code shows the final comparison, the first two steps of sorting and removing non-unique are kind of trivial.

Answer (score 0):

While the removeAll seems to be the way to go, here's another option:

I should mention this only works if the arrays are sorted in order.

Start at the beginning of each array.  If the values match, step to the next index in both.  If they don't match, report the lower value as missing in the other array, then increase the index of the lower value array only.  Compare again.  If you reach the end of one array but not both, anything left over is missing in the array that ended.

Good luck!